# v4l2-ctl exposure-auto setting fails

Tags: webcam, camera, video4linux

I am trying to tune a C920 webcam for picture quality using `v4l2-ctl` utility on Ubuntu PC. I am unable to set exposure_auto to 'Auto' mode, but I am able to set it to 'Manual Mode' or in 'Aperture Priority Mode'. Any clues?

```
*lenovo@ubuntu:~$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_auto=0
VIDIOC_S_CTRL: failed: Input/output error
exposure_auto: Input/output error*
```

Following are the settings dump of C920 connected to my ubuntu:

```
 - brightness (int) : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
 - contrast (int) : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
 - saturation (int) : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
 - white_balance_temperature_auto (bool) : default=1 value=1 
 - gain (int) : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=0 value=0 
 - power_line_frequency (menu) : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=2
 - white_balance_temperature (int) : min=2000 max=6500 step=1 default=4000 value=4000  
 - sharpness (int) : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128 
 - backlight_compensation (int) : min=0 max=1    step=1 default=0 value=0 
 - exposure_auto (menu) : min=0 max=3 default=3    value=3  (0: Auto Mode 1: Manual Mode
           2: Shutter Priority Mode
           3: Aperture Priority Mode) 
 - exposure_absolute (int) : min=3 max=2047 step=1 default=250 value=250  
 - exposure_auto_priority (bool) :    default=0 value=1 
 - focus_absolute (int) : min=0 max=250 step=5    default=0 value=0 
 - focus_auto (bool) : default=1 value=1 
 - zoom_absolute    (int) : min=100 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=100
```

Comment: Setting `exposure_auto_priority` to 0, I set `exposure_absolute` to the maximum value on this model, expecting to get faint images. However the images I am getting look as colorful as with the default value. So no idea right now whether the driver and hardware are actually responding to this value or not, on this model.

Answer (score 8):

That usually happens when you try to manually set a setting which is currently controlled by some other automatic. Try toggling ''exposure_auto_priority'' to see if that looses the grip of the auto algorithm on that particular setting.

For me, for example, setting  ''white_balance_temperature_auto'' to 0 allowed me to manually set ''white_balance_temperature'' which resulted in "failed: Input/output error" before.

Answer (score 6):

Using

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_auto=1
```

instead of `exposure_auto = 0`, you can set exposure to manual then set `exposure_absolute` to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it's easy to find out what parameters your camera accepts with uvcdynctrl

```
sudo apt install uvcdynctrl
```

To get a list of all supported commands type:

```
uvcdynctrl -c -v
```

-c will give you a list of all available settings

-v stands for verbose, giving you the range of values accepted

my Microsoft Lifecam will give me this output:

```
  Brightness
    ID      : 0x00000001,
    Type    : Dword,
    Flags   : { CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE },
    Values  : [ 30 .. 255, step size: 1 ],
    Default : 133
  Contrast
    ID      : 0x00000002,
    Type    : Dword,
    Flags   : { CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE },
    Values  : [ 0 .. 10, step size: 1 ],
    Default : 5
  Saturation
    ID      : 0x00000004,
    Type    : Dword,
    Flags   : { CAN_READ, CAN_WRITE },
    Values  : [ 0 .. 200, step size: 1 ],
    Default : 83
```

.. and so on.

You can then get the actual value with

```
uvcdynctrl -g 'Exposure, Auto'
```

or set the value with

```
uvcdynctrl -s 'Exposure, Auto' 1
```

Comment: any idea what might be the units for _exposure_absolute_? Is that Hz?