# Ubuntu 12 with logitech c525 webcam, and disabling auto exposure inside a virtual machine

Tags: webcam, vmware-player

This problem may be related to [v4l2 ctl exposure-auto-setting fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211971/v4l2-ctl-exposure-auto-setting-fails) which has not been answered and has remained opened since November.

I am using the c525 with OpenCV, and for my application to work properly, I need to disable  auto exposure, the exposure automatic priority, and the auto focus.

Default settings from Video4Linux Control Panel: [image]

When I try and change exposure auto priority: [image]

I am running my application in a VMWare Player instance, running Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64, with a Windows 7 64 bit host.

I currently don't have the option of doing a full install of Ubuntu, but I don't see why this would be an issue with running inside a virtual machine.

**Update:**

I fiddled with the settings, and was able to change auto exposure priority, but then inside OpenCV, I get a lot of device timeouts.